# Запуск python скрипта на хостинге от Beget

Tags: python

У меня есть два файла: один с расширением .py, второй с .html

Бекенд и фронтенд

Я заливаю их в файловый менеджер на хост. Не работает. Говорили, что питон скрипт нужно как то запустить.

Файлы прикрепил. Помогите разобраться, чтобы всё работало. Отпишитесь, пожалуйста. Срочно нужно.

Файл с расширением .py:

```
import asyncio
import logging
import websockets
import socketio
import asyncpg
import time
import json

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('engineio').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logging.getLogger('socketio').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
#token = "" #jaywetee2
#token = "" #avataria
#token = "" #jaywetee
sio = socketio.AsyncClient()
users = {"donations": {"client": "jaywetee"}, "333": {"client_333": "jaywetee"}}
connected_users = {"donations": [], "333": []}

@sio.on('connect')
async def on_connect_client():
    print("Подключились к Donation Alerts!")
    await sio.emit('add-user', {'token': token, 'type': 'minor'})

@sio.on('disconnect')
async def on_disconnect_client():
    print("Вылетели из Donation Alerts!")

@sio.on('donation')
async def on_donate(data):
    print("Пришёл донат!")
    data = json.loads(data)
    print(data)
    async with pool.acquire() as db:
        username = data["username"][:14].replace(".", ",")
        if data["amount_main"] < 99 or username == "":
            return
        don = await db.fetchrow("SELECT * FROM donate WHERE name = $1", data["username"])
        if don:
            if don["sum"] < data["amount_main"]:
                await db.execute("UPDATE donate SET sum = $1, date = $2 WHERE name = $3", data["amount_main"], time.time(), data["username"])
                tmp = []
                send = False
                i = 1
                for item in await db.fetch("SELECT * FROM donate ORDER BY sum DESC, date ASC LIMIT 3"):
                    if username == item["name"]:
                        send = True
                    tmp.append({"user": item["name"][:14].replace(".", ","), "place": i})
                    i += 1
                del i
                if send:
                    await asyncio.wait([user[0].send(json.dumps({"action": "top_donations", "donations": tmp})) for user in connected_users["donations"]])
            return
        await db.execute("INSERT INTO donate(name, sum, message, date) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)", data["username"], data["amount_main"], data["message"], time.time())
        try:
            await asyncio.wait([user[0].send(json.dumps({"action": "donation", "user": username, "sum": data["amount_main"], "message": data["message"]})) for user in connected_users["donations"]])
            tmp = []
            i = 1
            for item in await db.fetch("SELECT * FROM donate ORDER BY sum DESC, date ASC LIMIT 3"):
                tmp.append({"user": item["name"][:14].replace(".", ","), "place": i})
                i += 1
            del i
            await asyncio.wait([user[0].send(json.dumps({"action": "top_donations", "donations": tmp})) for user in connected_users["donations"]])
        except ValueError:
            pass
        try:
            if data["amount_main"] >= 333:
                await asyncio.wait([user[0].send(json.dumps({"action": "donation", "user": username, "sum": data["amount_main"], "message": data["message"]})) for user in connected_users["333"]])
        except ValueError:
            pass

async def handle_websocket(websocket, path):
    data = json.loads(await websocket.recv())
    if data["action"] == "auth":
        if data["key"] in users["donations"]:
            username = users["donations"][data["key"]]
            kek = "donations"
            connected_users["donations"].append([websocket, username])
            logging.info("Подключился "+username)
            tmp = []
            async with pool.acquire() as db:
                for item in await db.fetch("SELECT * FROM donate ORDER BY id ASC"):
                    tmp.append({"user": item["name"][:14].replace(".", ","), "sum": item["sum"], "message": item["message"]})
                await websocket.send(json.dumps({"action": "old_donations", "donations": tmp}))
                tmp = []
                i = 1
                for item in await db.fetch("SELECT * FROM donate ORDER BY sum DESC, date ASC LIMIT 3"):
                    tmp.append({"user": item["name"][:14].replace(".", ","), "place": i})
                    i += 1
                del i
                await websocket.send(json.dumps({"action": "top_donations", "donations": tmp}))
            del tmp
        elif data["key"] in users["333"]:
            username = users["333"][data["key"]]
            kek = "333"
            connected_users["333"].append([websocket, username])
            logging.info("Подключился "+username)
            tmp = []
            async with pool.acquire() as db:
                for item in await db.fetch("SELECT * FROM donate WHERE sum >= 333 ORDER BY id ASC"):
                    tmp.append({"user": item["name"][:14].replace(".", ","), "sum": item["sum"], "message": item["message"]})
                await websocket.send(json.dumps({"action": "old_donations", "donations": tmp}))
        else:
            logging.info("Неверный ключ: "+data["key"])
            return
    else:
        logging.info("???")
        return
    try:
        async for message in websocket:
            logging.info(message)
    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
        pass
    finally:
        logging.info("Отключился "+username)
        connected_users[kek].remove([websocket, username])

async def main():
    global pool
    pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(database="bot", user="bot")
    await websockets.serve(handle_websocket, '0.0.0.0', 8765)
    await sio.connect('wss://socket.donationalerts.ru:443')
    await sio.wait()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Файл с расширением .html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var socket = new WebSocket("");
        socket.onopen = function() {
            socket.send(JSON.stringify({ action: "", key: "" }));
            console.log("Соединение установлено.");
        };

        socket.onclose = function(event) {
            if (event.wasClean) {
                console.log('Соединение закрыто чисто');
            } else {
                console.log('Обрыв соединения'); // например, "убит" процесс сервера
            }
            console.log('Код: ' + event.code + ' причина: ' + event.reason);
        };

        socket.onmessage = function(event) {
            console.log("Получены данные:");
            data = JSON.parse(event.data);
            console.log(data);
            if (data.action === "donation") {
                addToPage(data.user);
            } else if (data.action == "old_donations") {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.donations.length; i++) {
                    addToPage(data.donations[i].user);
                }
            } else if (data.action == "top_donations") {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.donations.length; i++) {
                    setPlace(data.donations[i].user, data.donations[i].place);
                }
            }
        };

        socket.onerror = function(error) {
            console.log("Ошибка " + error.message);
        };

        function setPlace(name, place) {
            var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
            var animation = false;
            for (i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
                var tmp = tags[i].textContent.split('.')[1];
                if (tmp == name+' ') {
                    switch(place){
                        case 1:
                            var tag = 'first';
                            var kek = document.getElementsByClassName('first');
                            if(kek.length != 0) {
                                kek[0].classList.add('second');
                                kek[0].classList.remove('first');
                            }
                            var kek = document.getElementsByClassName('second');
                            if(kek.length != 0) {
                                kek[0].classList.add('third');
                                kek[0].classList.remove('second');
                            }
                            var kek = document.getElementsByClassName('third');
                            if(kek.length != 0) {
                                kek[0].removeChild(kek[0].childNodes[1]);
                                kek[0].classList.remove('third');
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            var tag = 'second';
                            var kek = document.getElementsByClassName('second');
                            if(kek.length != 0) {
                                kek[0].classList.add('third');
                                kek[0].classList.remove('second');
                            }
                            var kek = document.getElementsByClassName('third');
                            if(kek.length != 0) {
                                kek[0].removeChild(kek[0].childNodes[1]);
                                kek[0].classList.remove('third');
                            }
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            var tag = 'third';
                            var kek = document.getElementsByClassName('third');
                            if(kek.length != 0) {
                                kek[0].removeChild(kek[0].childNodes[1]);
                                kek[0].classList.remove('third');
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            console.log("капец place неправильный");
                            return null;
                    }
                    tags[i].classList.add(tag);
                    tags[i].innerHTML += '<i class="fas fa-trophy"></i>';
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        function addToPage(name) {
            var len = document.getElementsByTagName("p").length;
            var div1 = document.getElementById('donations1')
            var div = div1;
            element = document.createElement('p');
            element.innerHTML = (len+1)+'.'+name+' ';
            element.classList.add('animated', 'bounceInRight');
            div.appendChild(element);
        };
    </script>
    <div class="kek"><div id="donations1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ну так обращайтесь к документации или техподдержке Beget, им там виднее

Comment: Html страница в принципе открывается?

Comment: Да пустая страница открывается!